# How to remove "Sure, here is the test version of <action name>" from google actions demo?

Tags: actions-on-google

Literally the header says it all. 
I couldn't find anything online or in the docs neither in G+ community. 
It's very annoying as I don't want my action to be globally available and just for my experiments and showing around.

I don't want

```
Sure, here is the test version of <action name>
```

everytime I call for my agent

Answer (score 2):

Test version is not available globally. It's only for simulation. Once you submit the action for review and get approval then your action will be globally. Then it will say:

```
Sure, here's <action name>
```